# JSON arrary accessing undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having difficulty accessing the value a simple JSON array...how do I extract the "testresult" in this case?
Thanks in advance

```
var submittedSearchJSON = [];
submittedSearchJSON.push({"test": "testresult"}); 
console.log(submittedSearchJSON)
console.log(submittedSearchJSON.test)
console.log(submittedSearchJSON["test"])
```

The above results in:
[{test:"testresult"}]
undefined
undefined

Comment: Look at what you are referencing. It is an array, not the object in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use the index to access the Array object first

```
var submittedSearchJSON = [];
submittedSearchJSON.push( {"test": "testresult"} );

console.log( submittedSearchJSON ); // [object Array]
console.log( submittedSearchJSON[0].test ); // "testresult"
console.log( submittedSearchJSON[0]["test"] ); // "testresult"
```